# rotating text with fade-in

Tags: text, fading

I currently have this code for displaying random customer testimonials.
I would like to replace the random function with a code that will display the quotes by their order and then repeat them.

```
<html style="direction:rtl;">
  <DIV id=textrotator style="FONT: 16px arial ; text-align:right; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: rgb(255,255,255)"></DIV>
  <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" alink="#FFFFFF" vlink="#FFFFFF" topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" rightmargin="0">
  <script type = "text/javascript">
    var hexinput = 255; // initial color value.

    quotation = new Array()
    quotation[0] = "text1"
    quotation[1] = "text2"
    quotation[2] = "text3"

    function fadingtext()
    { 
      if(hexinput >111) 
      { 
        hexinput -=11; // increase color value
        document.getElementById("textrotator").style.color="rgb("+hexinput+","+hexinput+","+hexinput+")"; // Set color value.
        setTimeout("fadingtext()",200); // 200ms per step
      }
      else 
      {
        hexinput = 255; //reset hex value
      }
    }

    function changetext()
    {
      if(!document.getElementById){return}
      var which = Math.round(Math.random()*(quotation.length - 1)); 
      document.getElementById("textrotator").innerHTML = quotation[which]; 
      fadingtext();
      setTimeout("changetext()",8000); 
    }

    window.onload = changetext();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your index global.  Throw `which` outside of the function and then just increment it, make sure to wrap when you get to the end.

This is the replacement for the "changetext" function:

```
var which = 0;

function changetext()
{
    which += 1; 
    if (which >= quotation.length)
    {
        which = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("textrotator").innerHTML = quotation[which]; 

    fadingtext();

    setTimeout("changetext()",8000);
}
```

Comment: @user2479629 Ok, could you mark it as "accepted" then?  (The green checkbox below the up/number/down to the left of this answer.)  Thanks. :)